# Notification URL in PayPal Sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to PayPal Process.
I have a testing Subscription Page in `ASP.Net` which redirects to `PayPal Sandbox` for Payment in which I have PayPal business account with **Notification URL** specified in `Instant Payment Notification (IPN)` with **Message delivery Enabled** but after the user Agree and Pay the respective amount the page is not been redirected to the **notify_url**

My PayPal Processing page sites,

```
<input name="return" type="hidden" id="Hidden1" value="@MyClass.Domain.Common.WebAppSettings.AspxOldUrl/Thanks.aspx" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="@MyClass.Domain.Common.WebAppSettings.AspxOldUrl/Cancellation.aspx" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="@MyClass.Domain.Common.WebAppSettings.AspxOldUrl/ThankYou.aspx" />
```

I had checked all the settings in PayPal that redirects to the **notify_url** but its not working

Kindly anyone point me what I am missing in the settings or going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused `notify_url` with the return URL (variable: `return`). What you may want to trun on is the **Auto Retrun** feature under **website preference** section in your PayPal profile.

Additionally, in your subscription button code, you may put in the return tag to override the URL that you setup in your profile.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://bt-pduan-1.c9.io/">
```

Comment: @pp_pudan I had tried the **Auto Return** feature also but it also didn't workout well